# Finding Prime Number and the count of the Prime number - Python

Tags: python

I a beginner at Python, still a tad confused about it. I got to print out the prime numbers but now I am stuck trying to get the count of outputed prime numbers, please help.

```
import math

n= int (input("Enter an Integer: "))

for j in range(2, n+1):
    if all(j%i!=0 for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(j))+1)):
        print (j)



    count = 0
    for j in range(2, n+1):
        if j is True:
            len(j)
            print(str(len(j)))
```

Comment: Add a counter before the first for loop and set it to zero, then after every time you `print(j)` increment the counter. Then you can remove all the code that comes afterwards.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your problem is? Just increment count whenever you find a prime number. But you will need to move `count` outside of the first for loop as @alfasin mentioned.

Comment: It looks like in your code the last block, starting from `count=0`, is unnecessary. What you can do is move the assignment of `count` to before the for loop, and increment count every time the if statement inside the for loop is true. The second for loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that your aim is to print all the prime numbers between 0 and n (Taken as input by the user) and count them. All you have to do is declare 'count' before the first loop and increment it everytime a prime number is found. The code will look something like this :

```
import math

n= int (input("Enter an Integer: "))
count = 0
for j in range(2, n+1):
    if all(j%i!=0 for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(j))+1)):
        print (j)
        count = count + 1
print (" Number of prime numbers is : " , count)
```

What is wrong in your code is that, in the second loop `for j in range(2, n+1):` , j is an integer and `if j is True:` is always false, as j is not a 'boolean' value. Hence `print(str(len(j)))` is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add a counter in your code. Please go through the code below to see how that can be done.

```
import math

n= int (input("Enter an Integer: "))
count = 0
for j in range(2, n+1):
    if all(j%i!=0 for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(j))+1)):
        print (j)
        count = count + 1

print "Number of prime numbers between 1 and " + str(n) + " is " + str(count)
```